# Can I use \mapsto with a Cartesian input?

Tags: functions, notation

I have a function

$$
f: X \times O \to Y
$$

in my publication's definition. I would like to change it to

$$
f: x \times o \mapsto y
$$

where $x\in X, o\in O, y\in Y$. It this notation still valid?

Alternatively, would it be valid if I write

$$
f: X \times O \to Y
$$

if X is a infinite set and O is a finite multiset?

Comment: You should write $(x,o)\mapsto y$. (The elements of Cartesians products are called tuples).

Comment: If I tell you that $f: 1 \times 2 \mapsto 3$ does that describe the domain and codomain of $f$?

Comment: @Milten: Thanks! I should have figured that out. Is the second option valid? (See edit.)

Comment: these symbols don't have completely universal meanings, but usually when we use $x \mapsto y$ notation, we don't repeat the name of the function.

Comment: I don’t think having functions with a multiset domain is standard. What do you want exactly? If you have two identical elements in the domain, are they allowed to map to different elements of $Y$? E.g. if $f:\{1,1\}\to \{1,2\}$, then what would allowable functions look like in this case?

Comment: @Milten: No, what would map is $1, 2 \mapsto 3$ and if the second element of the input tuple is a "different" 2, the result would still be 3. Alternatively, I could define an $O'$, which is the underlying set of the mutliset $O$, but I am not sure there is a notation for "... is the underlying set of the multiset ...".

Comment: Okay, then I would just write “$f:X\times O’\to Y$, where $O’$ is the underlying set of $O$”. That should make anyone happy.

Comment: And you need this construction several times, just define your own notation for the underlying set.

Comment: @Milten: Thanks! I love your last point, but my paper is already full of newly invented notation :-D. The reviewers will kill me, i.e., reject my paper. I just also found the expressions that *O is drawn from a set O'* http://c4i.gmu.edu/ursw/2010/papers/URSW2010_F1_Jiang.pdf or that *O is drawn from a universe O'* https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/27900.

Comment: You could also just specify that whenever you have a function with a multiset as domain, it is understood to be a function from the underlying set. The world’s your oyster!

Comment: @Milten: I am writing a machine learning paper. I got multiple "what's up with this strange notation" from reviewers, after introducing notation. Once I got - which had nothing to do with notation - the reply that there was to much math in the paper, who should be able to understand that? I mean, I had *proofs* in the paper for crying out loud - that was just bad manners on my part ;-). (Btw. I did not even study math, but engineering.) I got good feedback from some reviewers, but some reviews are kind of arbitrary and those are the ones that might kill the paper.